# Distributing N balls in B baskets with equal probability.

Tags: probability

I have $N$ balls and $B$ baskets. I look at each basket $i$ in turn, and decide with some probability $P_i$ whether to insert one ball. After $N$ balls have been inserted, I have run out and stop. If I look through all baskets $B$, I stop; I do not do a second run-through even if I haven't inserted all $N$ balls.

Is it possible for $P_i$ to be written such that it seems as if the distribution of the balls had been randomised (while avoiding more than one ball per basket)? i.e. that the chance any one basket receives a ball is $N/B$? $P_i$ can't be a static number if $N < B$, for instance if $B = 100, N = 1$ and $P_i = 0.5$ then there is an incredibly small chance that basket number 50 obtains a ball in comparison to basket number 1. However when $N >= B$ then I could have a static number for $P_i$ because there enough balls to supply for each basket and the chance isn't affected by whether balls have been inserted in previous baskets.

$P_i$ may even vary with the number of balls remaining (since $P_i$ can be static depending on whether $N < B$ or $N >= B$). But I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

Comment: Not sure I'm following.  if $N≥B$ then wouldn't any constant probability work?  If $N<B$ then no non-zero probability (constant or variable) could work.

Comment: @lulu Oh I know if $N \geq B$ then any constant probability works, I say that. But if $N < B$ why can't it be possible? There's no way to write $P$ as a function of remaining baskets and $N$ such that each basket will, overall, have an equal opportunity of obtaining a ball? Why is that?

Comment: @lulu I agree with your interpretation (for $N<B$); if $P_i$ is the probability given for basket $i$, then $P_i<P_{i-1}<P_{i-2}<\dots$, since $P_i$ depends on all the probabilities going before it and all those are smaller than one.

Comment: Well...maybe I was wrong.  Let's see.  Say $B=2$, $n=1$.  Then we let $p_1=\frac 12$ $p_2=1$.  That seems to give a probability $\frac 12$ for both bins.  So, ok.  I was too hasty.

Comment: Recursively, if we fix $n$ and solve the problem for $B-1$ bins then it's pretty clear that we can push the solution to $B$...

Comment: It comes down to the exact rules of the game.  Look at my proposed solution for $B=2,n=1$.  Is that valid?  for it to make sense, you have to imagine that the game stops if I run out of balls.  Doesn't make sense to say $p_2=1$ if there are no more balls, so I have to declare that we simply don't consider the second bin if we put the ball in the first.

Comment: @lulu Yeah, the game would stop after no more balls are left.

Comment: So you accept my solution in the special case?  If so, then I think you'll be able to solve the general case inductively.  To get started, I recommend first solving the case $n=1$ for general $B$.  I've done $B=2$...can you do $B=3$?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what @Lovsovs said. $P_i$ is the probability function we create. I think in general $P_i$ should be greater than $P_{i-1}$, because the chances of reaching the $i$th box is lower, and so the chances a ball gets inserted ($P_i$) should be greater if we want an "equal" probability for all boxes. If he was saying the chance that a later box gets a ball is always lower than an earlier one, that isn't true: just take $N = 1$, $B = 2$, $P_1 = 0.25$ and $P_2 = 0.75$.

Comment: @lulu I will have a try now, thanks.

Comment: @lulu Well for $N=1$ I got $P_i = (1/(B-(i-1)))$. Not sure if you got the same if you worked it out, now to figure out for general N! That's going to be tough.

Comment: But you have to admit it's a nice answer for $N=1$! i suppose it suggests that a natural target for larger $N$ is $\frac NB$.  Not that your claiming uniqueness or anything, but it's easier to work to a particular target.